# Xodus Entity Store: Finding properties that contain a value

Tags: xodus

I do understand that Xodus' Entity Store provides `StoreTransaction.find(..)` which matches properties with the exact provided value and `StoreTransaction.findStartingWith(..)` which matches properties beginning with the provided value.

What I don't see is a `StoreTransaction.findContains(..)` or a *LIKE* of any sort. How would I approach such a search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In version 1.3.232, there is no such. It makes sense to [file a feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=XD).

Comment: I just created https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/XD-824. Please vote for this feature request.